# Determining whether the event $E = \{\omega: \exists M \in \mathbb{R}: |X_n(\omega)|\leq M, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ belongs to tail sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing, random-variables

Let  $E = \{\omega: \exists M \in \mathbb{R}: |X_n(\omega)|\leq M, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be the event that the sequence $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. I'd like to determine whether or not this event belongs to the tail sigma algebra $\sigma_{\infty} = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\sigma\left(X_n, X_{n+1},\dots\right)$. While I'd like to say that the event does belong to the tail sigma-algebra I still can't overcome the following thought: For there to exist some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|X_n| \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it would have to be that given any finite portion of the sequence, say $X_1,\dots, X_N, N\in \mathbb{N}$, then we'd have to have that $|X_i| \leq M, i = 1,\dots,N$. Therefore given any constant $M$, we can trivially force $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = M + 1) = 1$, so that whether the sequence $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded for that particular value $M$ depends on a finite subcollection of the random variables. Is my reasoning valid or is it self-contradictory in the sense that under assumption the realizations of the random variables of the sequence have to be bounded by some constant $M \in \mathbb{R}$ implying, in turn, that how any finite portion of the sequence behaves is not of importance, since it is bounded by assumption?

Comment: Your first intuition says that if $M$ were fixed, then the event that the sequence $(X_n)$ is bounded by $M$ is generally not in the tail $\sigma$-algebra. But that isn't what is asked here. We know that a sequence of real numbers is bounded if and only if it's tails are bounded. This translates almost directly into a proof that $E$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Mason You are perhaps correct about my initial thoughts: I was/am confused on how restricted the values of the random sequences are in $E$, but it seems reasonable that they are, in fact, restricted by assumption. In any case, how could we then finish the proof (I'm clueless regarding these sort of $\sigma$ proofs) By showing that its complement is in the tail sigma-algebra, and using the properties of sigma-algebras? Like $E^c = \bigcap_{k = 1}^\infty\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty\{|X_n| \geq \frac{1}{k}\}$?

Comment: To start, we need to show that $E$ is at least $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots)$ measurable. This is simple since $E = \{\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|X_n| < \infty\}$. Can you extend this to show that $E$ is $\sigma\{X_m : m \geq n\}$ measurable for every $n$?

Comment: @Mason Okay, so $E$ is $\sigma(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ measurable because the random variable of the event $E$ is the supremum over all $X_n$. In other words, as $E$ handles each of the r.v.s $X_n$, then $E$ must belong to the sigma algebra generated by all the random variables. Because $\sup_{n\geq m}X_n$ is non-increasing in $m$, it follows that omitting finitely many terms does not affect $\inf_m(\sup_{n\geq m}X_n)$.  Therefore $E \in \sigma(X_m, X_{m+1},\dots)$ for every $m$ and by definition $E \in \sigma_{\infty}$? (continues)

Comment: Why are you talking about $\inf$? You mixed up this question with another one.

Comment: @Mason I had stumbled across a result showing that the limit superior and inferior of any random sequence are measurable w.r.t. $\sigma_{\infty}$. As I have no real idea on how to continue the observation that $\sup_{n\geq m}X_n$ is non-decreasing w.r.t. $m$ I tried to borrow parts of the said result to finish this claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $E = \{\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|X_n| < \infty\}$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. I will assume that $X_n$ are real valued. Then since $|X_n| < \infty$ for each $n$, we have $E = \{\sup_{n \geq N}|X_n| < \infty\}$. If $n \geq N$, then $X_n$ is $\sigma\{X_m : m \geq N\}$-measurable. Therefore $\sup_{n \geq N}|X_n|$ is $\sigma\{X_m : m \geq N\}$-measurable. Hence $E \in \sigma\{X_m : m \geq N\}$. Since this holds for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $E$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: This feels similar, yet more succinct and rigorous to the ramble I produced in the comments, thanks! The gist of the problem seemed to be the connection between the supremum and partial tail ($\sigma\{X_m:m \geq N\}$) measurability.

Comment: @EpsilonAway Yes. The key fact is that if $f_1, f_2, \dots : \Omega \to [-\infty, \infty]$ are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, then $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f_n$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.